# JQ Widgets and IE 9 issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, lotus-notes, jqwidget

From past couple of days I am pulling my hairs to find out why Jqwidgets are not looking good on IE9 when everything perfect on Firefox and Chrome.

On Firefox (version-34.0.1)
[image]

On Chrome (version-40.0.2214.115)
[image]

On IE (version-9.0.8112)
[image]

Toolbar looks specially horrible,

```
$("#jqxToolBar").jqxToolBar({
                tools: 'custom | dropdownlist | custom | dropdownlist | custom | button | button | custom',
                initTools: function (type, index, tool, menuToolIninitialization) {
                   switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                tool.append("<div style='font-weight: bold;padding: 3px;'>Select Level :</div>");
                break;
                        case 1:
                           var levelsource = <Computed Value>;
                            tool.jqxDropDownList({ width: 200, source: levelsource, placeHolder: "Select..."});
                if (menuToolIninitialization === false) {
                                dropdownlist1 = tool;
                             } else {
                                dropdownlist1Min = tool;
                             }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                tool.append("<div style='font-weight: bold;padding: 3px;'>Select :</div>");
                break;
              tool.append("<div style='padding: 3px;'></div>");
//                       tool.append("<div style='font-weight: bold;'>Select</div>");
//                           dropdownlist1.add(dropdownlist1Min).on('select', function (event) {
//             tool.append("<div style='font-weight: bold;'>Select "+event.args.item.label+"</div>");
//            });
                break;
                        case 3:
                              var resultsource = <Computed Value>;
                            tool.jqxDropDownList({ width: 200, source: [], placeHolder: "Select..."});
                if (menuToolIninitialization === false) {
                                dropdownlist2 = tool;
                            } else {
                                dropdownlist2Min = tool;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                tool.append("<div style='padding: 10px;'></div>");
                break;
                        case 5:
                            tool.jqxButton({ width: '80px',template: "success"});
                tool.text("Apply filter");
                tool.click(function() {
                    if(dropdownlist1.jqxDropDownList('getSelectedItem')!=null )
                                {
            if(dropdownlist2.jqxDropDownList('getSelectedItem')!=null )
                                    {
                    var datafield= dropdownlist1.jqxDropDownList('getSelectedItem').value;
                    switch (datafield) 
                   {
                         case "Vessel":
                 applyFilter("opcenter");
                                                     break;
                 case "Project":
                 applyFilter("project_name");
                                                     break;
                 case "Region":
                 applyFilter("region");
                                                     break;
                 case "Client":
                 applyFilter("client");
                                                     break;
                 case "Maritime Manager":
                 applyFilter("maritimemanager");
                                                     break;
                 case "Global":
                         $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
//               $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({ source: getAdapter() });
                                                     break;
                                             }
                                        }
            }
            return false;
         });
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            tool.jqxButton({ width: '80px',template: "info"});
                tool.text("Clear filter");
                tool.click(function() {
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
                            //dropdownlist1.jqxDropDownList({ selectedIndex: -1 });
                            //dropdownlist2.jqxDropDownList({ selectedIndex: -1 });
                return false;
                        });
                            break;                          
                        case 7:
                            tool.jqxListBox({source: listSource, width: '100%', height: 300,  checkboxes: true });
                if (menuToolIninitialization === false) {
                                listbox= tool;
                             } else {
                                listboxMin= tool;
                             }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

My html ,

```
<body class="default">
<table id='jqxWidget' border="0">
            <tr>
       <td>
                          <div id="jqxToolBar"> 
                         </div>
                   </td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>
        <div id='jqxExpander'>
            <div>Date filter</div>
               <div>
                <table border="0" >
                   <tr>
                          <td><b>Start date : </b></td>
                          <td id="jqxStDtWidget"></td>
                          <td><b>End date :</b></td>
                          <td id="jqxEnDtWidget"></td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td id="jqxDateFilterWidget"></td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          <td><input type="button" id='jqxApplyFilterButton' value="Apply filter" /></td>
                          <td><input type="button" id='jqxClearFilterButton' value="Clear filter" /></td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
               </div>
        </div>
                    </td>
              </tr>     
              <tr>
                    <td>
                               <div style="float: left;" id="jqxgrid"></div>
                    </td>
              </tr>
```

Anyone encounter such weird behavior on IE9 ?

Edit: Another thing I have tested to find out why date picker size is different between Firefox and Chrome and when investigated found there is different css applied on the same picker on different browser. Any thoughts why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The internet is heavily populated with people having issues with JQuery / JQueryUI JQWidgets / HTML5 on IE9.

The versions of Firefox and Chrome you have specified are much more modern than IE9. Until you are able to use a more modern version of IE you may continue to have issues.

Answer (score 0):

When things are not initialized correctly, issues should be expected :) especially when you create widgets from not-supported HTML Elements. I suggest you to learn and read before write own code. The problem in your code is that you create widgets from TD tags where DIV tags are expected.

Comment: there is documentation and examples which showcase how things should be done correctly. There's no magic, just do it as shown there.

Comment: Got the issue. Found my IE was running in "compatibility" mode all the time and there is no option to disable the "compatibility" mode due to this option is disabled.So I have added following line in my <head> section and all looks fine on IE,

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

However, Still I am following same design approach like keeping DIV in TABLE because my design requires this approach.